# How to call generic struct in C++

Tags: c++, generics, struct, can-bus

I'm trying to make a class in which we can encode and decode different structs from and to a char*.

I'm doing this the following way I've made an abstract 
generic class called CANgenericMsg with CANgenericMsg.cpp being:

```
#include "CANgenericMsg.h"

CANgenericMsg::CANgenericMsg() {
     // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

void CANgenericMsg::decode(char* chars) {
    CANgenericMsg::str* data = reinterpret_cast<CANgenericMsg::str*>(chars);
    structure = *data;
}

char* CANgenericMsg::encode() {
     return reinterpret_cast<char*>(&structure);
}


CANgenericMsg::~CANgenericMsg() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
```

And with header:

```
class CANgenericMsg {
public:
    CANgenericMsg();
    void decode(char* chars);
    virtual ~CANgenericMsg();
    char* encode();
    virtual struct str structure;
};
```

This class is extended by real classes such as CANintegermsg, in which the constructor of this class inits the struct:

```
class CANintegermsg: public CANgenericMsg {
public:
     CANintegermsg(int i);
     virtual ~CANintegermsg();

    struct str {
        unsigned short int my_int;
    } structure;
};
```

The idea being that you can set a specific struct type in each extended class. The problem is that C++ doesn't recognize virtual structs. I could move the encode and decode functions to each extended class, but as there are a lot of them, this would result in code duplication. Does there exist a neat way to be able to use the encode and decode functions like this?

Comment: Consider also SWIG or an IDL like XPCOM or DCE/RPC IDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use templates:

```
template<class T>
class CANGenericMsg 
{
public:
    CANGenericMsg(const T val) : m_structureObj(val) {}
    void decode(char* chars)
    {
        T* data = reinterpret_cast<T*>(chars);
        m_structureObj = *data;
    }
    char* encode()
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<char*>(&m_structureObj);
    }
private:
    T m_structureObj;
};

struct StructUShortInt { unsigned short int my_int; };
using CANIntegerMsg = CANGenericMsg<StructUShortInt>;
```

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't thought of it this way. I've got 2 more questions:
1) What is exactly happening with the constructor of CANgenericMsg? I am not familar with that syntax to be honest.
2) When trying to build, I'm getting an error on the "using CANIntegerMsg" line. "error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'CANIntegerMsg'". Why would you want an expected name specifier in that situation?

Comment: @DaanR, 1) it was using [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to initialize m_structureObj, I've changed it to the conventional copy-constructor. 2) Please check [this code](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/EGrO9qe8Cilwq9M4): it compiles with most compilers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Apearently my compiler isn't most compilers, but it seems to work just to interchange the "using" line to:

     "typedef CANGenericMsg<StructUShortInt> CANIntegerMsg;"

Comment: @DaanR ah, probably an older compiler not supporting c++11 (I had to mention it) :)

Comment: @DaanR if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419). This indicates that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I have one more question. Now we need 2 lines to create an object. One to init the struct and one to init the object with the struct. Is it possible for the constructor to be called like "CANIntegerMsg boo(2)" instead of "    StructUShortInt foo = {2}; CANIntegerMsg boo(foo);"? So is it possible to create the constructor of the class in such way we can fill in the variables that we need to automatically create the struct?

Comment: @DaanR sure, you just need a constructor that creates a struct from the elementary type. You could try something like [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/seZOAE74tUfBogGV).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds (please correct me if I am wrong) like you are trying to re-implement something like [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) (protobufs).
You could use a combination of protobuf messages, sub-messages and [extensions](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#extensions) to achieve you goal.

Protobufs are also easily [converted to & parsed from](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial#parsing-and-serialization) text and binary representations.

Comment: Thakn you for your answer! From what I read, I think these protobufs are suitable, but just using them for this single example would create more complexity in my opinion. I think that the "template" answer from AMA looks easier to implement. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @DaanR Indeed, if there is only one simple usage, you might be better off rolling a tailored implementation to avoid adding a dependency to an extra library. If you start defining many types of messages and things get out of hand, reconsider using a standard solution :)